# How can I emulate point sprites in D3D11?

Tags: c++, shaders, directx11

I have points which I pass to a vertex shader and then to a geometry shader, but now I want to get from the geometry shader a "bigger" point. So the point should get a "dadius" like it was possible in Direct3D 9.

Can anyone help me what I have to write in my geometry shader? I actually have the following code, which only passes the point to the pixel shader.

```
void LightGeometryShader( point GeometryInputType input[1], inout PointStream<GeometryInputType> TriStream)
{
    GeometryInputType output;

    for( int i=0; i<1; i++ )
    {
        output.position = input[i].position;
        output.color = input[i].color;
        output.tex = input[i].tex;
        output.viewDirection = input[i].viewDirection;
        TriStream.Append( output );
    }
}
```

Comment: You could render billboards.

Comment: If I would take billboards is it possible that I have points with a pixel size of 3 and in the color, the passed point was?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass any vertex attributes you want in from IA to the VS, which in turn you can pass to the GS.  Create a `radius` attribute in your `InputLayout`.  The VS can pass that on to the GS, which in turn can use it to construct a view-aligned circle or a billboard of a circle texture via that radius value.  You could also just set it as a uniform if all your point sprites will be of the same size and save on update bandwidth a bit.

There are [GDSE articles on billboarding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/billboarding) and [a ton of information on billboarding online](https://www.google.com/search?q=billboard%20hlsl) once you get to that part.

Comment: Hi! Ok Thanks a lot, but I would like to have a method, where I don't have to move my points, because it's for visualizing point clouds and it is enough to move the camera instead of the data. I thought that there is maybe a easy and fast technique to give the points a radius, like calculating points exactly next to them. :)

Comment: I have no experience with point cloud visualization techniques, sorry.  There's some nifty JavaScript/WebGL demos of such, though, maybe you could look at how they do it and port it over to C++/D3D.